# Parallax background tiled imperfectly

Tags: libgdx, parallax

I have some problems with my parallax background images. I embedded a GIF below that shows the problems: (1) there's a black flickering line at the edge of the texture and (2) the movement is not smooth (and this isn't due to the GIF's small frame rate). I also added the short code for my `ScrollableImage` class, which is at the heart of how I implemented parallax. I suspected the problem might be due to the modulo operation inside the `setScrollOffset` method, but that wasn't it and now I'm out of ideas. What should I try to fix this problem?

[image]

```
public class ScrollableImage extends Widget {

   private TextureRegion region;
   private float scrollOffset = 0.0f;

   public ScrollableImage(TextureRegion region) {
      this.region = region;
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
      super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

      float w = region.getRegionWidth();
      float h = region.getRegionHeight();

      float scale = getHeight() / h;
      float scaledWidth = w * scale;
      float scaledHeight = h * scale;
      float scaledOffset = scrollOffset * scale;

      Color color = getColor();
      batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);

      for (float x = getX() - scaledOffset; x < getX() +  getWidth(); x += scaledWidth) {
         batch.draw(region, x, getY(), scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
      }
   }

   public float getScrollOffset() {
      return scrollOffset;
   }

   public void setScrollOffset(float value) {
      scrollOffset = Math.max(0, value % (float)region.getRegionWidth());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem. In case someone runs into similar problems in the future, here's what I did. With the solution that gave me problems before, I was tiling the background from software (I had a for loop the was drawing the texture multiple times); what I did now and which works great is the use OpenGL's `GL_REPEAT`, which will use the hardware (the GPU) to repeat the texture. Here's my code:

```
public class ParallaxWidget extends Widget implements Disposable {

   private static final int LAYER_COUNT = 2;
   private Texture[] textures = new Texture[LAYER_COUNT];   
   private float[] scrollFactors = new float[LAYER_COUNT];
   private float[] scrollAmounts = new float[LAYER_COUNT];


   public ParallaxWidget(String path0, float factor0, String path1, float factor1) {
      scrollFactors[0] = factor0;
      scrollFactors[1] = factor1;

      scrollAmounts[0] = 0.0f;
      scrollAmounts[1] = 0.0f;

      textures[0] = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(path0));
      textures[1] = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(path1));

      textures[0].setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);
      textures[1].setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
      super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

      Color color = getColor();
      batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);

      for (int i = 0; i < LAYER_COUNT; ++i) {
         drawLayer(batch, i);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
       for (Texture texture : textures) {
           texture.dispose();
       }
   } 

   public void updateScroll(float value) {
      for (int i = 0; i < LAYER_COUNT; ++i) {
         scrollAmounts[i] = value * scrollFactors[i];
      }
   }

   private void drawLayer(Batch batch, int index) {
      float x = getX();
      float y = getY();

      float w = getWidth();
      float h = getHeight();

      float th = textures[index].getHeight();
      float tw = textures[index].getWidth() * h / th;

      float u = scrollAmounts[index] / tw;
      float v = 1.0f;

      float u2 = u + (w / tw);
      float v2 = 0.0f;

      batch.draw(textures[index], x, y, w, h, u, v, u2, v2);
   }
}
```