# Lbgdx: Repeating and scrolling background image

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine

Hi I am developing the game, where i need scrolling and repeating background. Following are my code:

Main Game Class:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

SpriteBatch batch;
BitmapFont font;
float bgX =0f;
Texture background,background2;
```

On Create:

```
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    background = new Texture("background.png");
    background2 = new Texture("background.png");
```

On Render:

```
public void render () {

    batch.begin();
    bgX -=1;
    batch.draw(background,bgX,0,background.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.draw(background2,background.getWidth() + bgX,0,background.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());


    if(bgX <- background.getWidth())
    {
        bgX = 0;
    }
```

On Dispose:

```
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();
    background.dispose();
```

However i get my desired result, but after mins, the scrolling becomes really slow.

**Is there any other better option?**

I need, background repeating scroll from right to left and background height is equal to Gdx.graphics.getHeight()

Thank you! in advance :)

Comment: Background.wrap or something like that needs to be set.

Comment: Here is a question that I've asked and answered on how to implemented scrolling parallax background in LibGDX. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24587722/627005

Answer (score 0):

you can simply achieve this by using "translate" method in libgdx. which will give you stable and constant output. please try this example.

```
 public class myGame extends ApplicationAdapter{
    public static Sprite sprite,sprite2;
    public static texture;
    public spriteBatch batch;
        public myGame () {

        }

        @Override
        public void create() {
            texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.png"));

            texture2 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.png"));
            sprite = new Sprite(texture, 0, 0, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
            sprite2 = new Sprite(texture2, 0, 0, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
            sprite.setPosition(0, 0);
            sprite2.setPosition(1280, 0);
            batch=new spriteBatch(sprite);



        }
     public void bckgroundMovment()
    {
sprite.translate(-1.5f, 0);

// here 1280 is the screen width
                sprite2.translate(-1.5f, 0);
                if (sprite.getX() < -1280) {
                    sprite.setPosition(1280, 0);
                }
                if (sprite2.getX() < -1280) {
                    sprite2.setPosition(1280, 0);
                }
    }
        @Override
        public void render(float delta) {
        bckgroundMovment()

    batch.begin()
    sprite.draw(batch);
    sprite2.draw(batch);
    batch.end();


        }

        @Override
        public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float deltaTime) {
            settingUp(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

            sprite.draw(batch);
            sprite2.draw(batch);
        }

    }

// it will defenitly work ..good luck
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I haven't noticed in your code, or you may have neglected to add, is to call `batch.end()`, which should always be called after `batch.begin()`.

I've implemented vertical/horizontal parallax backgrounds using Actors, but this should work for your approach:

```
public void render () {
  batch.begin();

  float left = bgX - 1;
  float backgroundWidth = background.getWidth();
  if (left <= -backgroundWidth) { // right side is now off the screen to the left
     bgX += backgroundWidth; // smoothly reset position
  }

  bgX -= 1; // continue scrolling

  batch.draw(background, bgX, 0, backgroundWidth, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
  batch.draw(background2, backgroundWidth + bgX, 0, backgroundWidth, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

  batch.end();
}
```